# How did they know that some Psychobuster still existed?

Tags: from-the-new-world

Saki's parents leave her a letter describing, roughly translated:

> Most of the weapons non-cantus-users created to defeat the
>   cantus-users have been rendered useless throughout the years. However,
>   one of them managed to survive this whole time: the Psychobuster. Here
>   is the address of its possible location - if you manage to find it,
>   you might be able to stop the demon.

The letter implies that they **know** (or at least, are fairly sure) that there is some Psychobuster out there that survived those centuries.

Of course, they aren't sure if Saki will be able to find the Psychobuster in the mentioned location, but they ARE sure that there must be one existing somewhere, which is what concerns me. How can they tell that there is still some left?

[image]

Comment: Personally, I think later in the series the show started going down the drain and they just had to come up with whatever cliche nonsense would help end the story.

Answer (score 2):

They are not sure that there are any weapons left, but the information regarding the existence of the Psychobuster itself is given to them most likely by a False Minoshiro.
As seen in the next episodes, it also helps them navigate to the presumed location of the Psychobuster.

It all about the hope of finding one. Similarly, the Queerats previously attempted to search for weapons to use against the cantus-users, with Kiromaru willing to sacrifice a large part of his expedition.